# Why is this legend in R not working?

Tags: r, plot

The plot is shown but the legend not.

```
df = data.frame(Year=c(2012,2013,2014), N=c(61175,52477,48699))
plot(df[,c('Year', 'N')], type='o')
legend(x=1, y=max(df$N), legend=c('a'), pch=1, lty=1)
```

I would expect it in the upper-left corner of the graphic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make your code work, you need

```
legend(x=min(df$Year), y=max(df$N), legend=c('a'), pch=1, lty=1)
```

`x=1` is outside the range of your x-axis. But of course, you should not place your legend on the top left corner in this case:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I was thinking in the way of _graphical_ coordinates. But of course the coordinates point to the data not the graphic. I have to change my way of thinking fundamentaly. ;)

Comment: btw: I saw another example where you can specify the position with a word like `"topleft"`. Nice.